# Conditional types giving error on function call but works with object literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Any idea why this is giving TS error?  Why can TS infer properly with literals but not with function returns.

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgYwRAziqBeKBvAsAKCihUWTQC4pgAnOCAbgIF8CDRIoAxAQwEsAbONWhY8hYqVQpKAM278UDAkQQB7ACYRKKGrwB2Ac0biAtlO4GtxXYeMt8bcNACiAD0gJgEdQCVUYVT1FTFhJNCgAHy4%20QWFWB3wZOD1PXkCoS2A-FACgiAAKbm0bAwBKHGUofghgKGEcyjcPL19-QMVjIl4ZKEKAOhIAIx1qfIBmUr7qw2AAC3KxIiJ6sBDM%20CQpfPKAeh2oABUnKABybAlNiihB1VVq7j16KCYTqF50PVVa7jReAz1uINqlRVFRjicmhBPN5srlFCc%20pUmFAIApoIslisQhilhcyNIoHI0QAaSq4tSaSgnAAsJ1J4lxZjQFisJzGJzJzyR8WWNSEejq-mY8QISRSwDSAvWYRQ2wq4mEwH58txJEuBJodG5%20HsBD2VFm7yIAHdVNQANboUXJVLpTKw9oQABMhWK1H0ZRVUAAbtxqIKGlBIdDWjlHZ03j1%20kMRuNJtMDHMFpysaJOUQ1fjKJqIJz7ERkajgjiA6s0wylpmpLJ5Ip6biVBpWc4ALQARgADB26emoEyUCyqUDuLMORX81yEryldQBSthQkgA)

```
type Success = {
  success: true;
}

type Failure = {
  success: false;
  code: string;
  message: string;
}

type ExpectedResponse = Success | Failure


function getResponse(a: string) {
  var resp: ExpectedResponse;
  if (a.substr(3).length) {
    // Error
    resp = getSuccess() // Type '{ success: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ExpectedResponse'.
  } else {
    resp = {
      success: false,
      code: '4',
      message: '3'
    }
  }

  return resp
}


function getSuccess() {
  return {
    success: true
  }
}

// this  works 
function getResponse2(a: string) {
  let resp: ExpectedResponse;
  if (a.substr(3).length) {
    resp = {
      success: true
    }
  } else {
    resp = {
      success: false,
      code: 'E-100',
      message: 'blah'
    }
  }

  return resp
}
```

this will work fine too

```
function getSuccess():Success {
  return {
    success: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you provide the appropriate return value, `function getSuccess(): Success { ... }`? Or use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). Otherwise it's just inferred as `{ success: boolean }` and TS can't determine whether or not you expect it to have the failure props.

Comment: that would work but if TS is inferring from literals , it would be reasonable to expect it can do it in this getSuccess function.

Comment: to rephrase my question:  Why can TS infer properly with literals but not with function returns ?

Comment: It infers more generally for return types without further information (like the `const` assertion or explicit return type) than literals. That's just how it's designed, because it's unusual (and sort of pointless) to write a function that only ever returns exactly one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the inferred type of

```
function getSuccess() {
  return {
    success: true
  }
}
```

Is `{ success: boolean; }` and not `{ success: true; }`.

If you want to prevent typescript from widening `true` to `boolean` you can use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
function getSuccess() {
  return {
    success: true
  } as const
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgYwRAziqBeKBvAsAKCihUWTQC4pgAnOCAbgIF8CDRIoAxAQwEsAbONWhY8hYqVQpKAM278UDAkQQB7ACYRKKGrwB2Ac0biAtlO4GtxXYeMt8bcNACiAD0gJgEdQCVUYVT1FTFhJNCgAHy4%20QWFWfBk4PU9eQKhLYD8UAKCIAApubRsDAEocZSh%20CGAoYWzKNw8vX39AxWMiXhkoAoA6EgAjHWo8gGYS3qrDYAALMrEiIjqwEIz4JCk8soB6bagAFScoAHJsCQ2KKAHVVSruPXooJmOoXnQ9VRruNF4DPW4BlUqKoqEdjo0IJ5vFkcopjr0KkwoBAFNAFotliF0YtzmRpFA5KiADQVHFqTSUY4AFmOJPEOLMaAsVmOo2OpKeiPiS2qQj0tX8zHiiWSwFS-LWYRQW3K4mEwD5spxJAu%20JodERUG%20UDUQWAQvwQA)